# Debugging resource strings are unavailable (Silverlight + MonoMac)

Tags: c#, silverlight, xaml, monomac

I have a Silverlight application that I have written a launcher for in Mac using MonoMac (basically an embedded web browser control that loads the page containing the SL xap). However, I keep getting an error that I can't for the life of me debug:

```
MS.Internal.WrappedException: Error 0x8000FFFF.  Debugging resource strings are unavailable. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=106663&Version=4.0.60531.0&File=mscorrc.dll&Key=0x8000FFFF  (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8000FFFF (E_UNEXPECTED)) ---> System.Exception: Error 0x8000FFFF.  Debugging resource strings are unavailable. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=106663&Version=4.0.60531.0&File=mscorrc.dll&Key=0x8000FFFF  (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8000FFFF (E_UNEXPECTED))
   at MS.Internal.XcpImports.CheckHResult(UInt32 hr)
   at MS.Internal.XcpImports.FrameworkElement_MeasureOverride(FrameworkElement element, Size availableSize)
   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureOverride(Size availableSize)
   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureOverride(IntPtr nativeTarget, Single inWidth, Single inHeight, Single& outWidth, Single& outHeight)
```

Now, I'm guessing this is some kind of Xaml exception of some sort, but I have no way to prove that and I have way too many Xaml files to look at them one-by-one. Does anyone know how to get these missing resource strings show up?

I have the Silverlight 4 Development Runtime installed on the Mac (I'm actually doing Remote Debugging from a Windows machine).

**Update**
The exception that is thrown goes away when the containing Xaml does not have a WebBrowser control. The xap loads and runs fine in Silverlight for Windows and Silverlight in-browser on Mac, but fails in OOB mode when there is a WebBrowser control in the visual tree.

Comment: Have you tried setting the privileges high for OOB? Just a wild guess.

Comment: How would I go about doing that?

Comment: Open the properties of your project, click Out-of-Browser Settings... and select Require elevated trust when running outside the browser

Comment: Is it possible for you to post some example code or something that generates the same error?

Answer (score 0):

Note, the following portion of the error:

> Debugging resource strings are unavailable. See
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=106663&Version=4.0.60531.0&File=mscorrc.dll&Key=0x8000FFFF

In order to keep the Silverlight runtime slim, a lot of strings were omitted in favour of links to them online. If you follow the link, it will tell you more about the error that you encountered.

> The definition of the resource ID could not be found.

It appears as though part of your code is referencing a resource key that doesn't exist.

Comment: Would not agree with your conclusion that "part of your code is referencing a resource key that doesn't exist".
If you open similar link for error information, it will show in a different format. E.g.
https://www.microsoft.com/getsilverlight/DllResourceIDs/Default.aspx?Version=5.1.50901.00&File=mscorlib.dll&Key=Arg_COMException
Change smth in that URL to become invalid, and it will show "The definition of the resource ID could not be found."
So it's a Microsoft message rather than developer's code related.